# Laravel 4 - Overriding cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable when build_from and slug are different

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, slug

I'm trying to set up a sluggable item in the database using cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable in Laravel 4. Its great when you want to force a title to adhere to a slug, but when it comes to making alterations I'm not sure what is the best way to approach it...

Imagine that someone creates a Post with a title "This is my post", sluggable converts it to "this-is-my-post" and does checks to ensure theres no duplicates in the table, or appends a "-1, -2" etc. this is great... however what I want is to do is add an optional form input called slug where a user can override the "build_from" variable in the Model, but retain checks on the override to ensure there are no duplicates.

So a title "This is my post", with a slug of 'foo-bar' should make it retain the slug, but at the moment when I save it reverts back to "this-is-my-post".

Is it possible to bypass build_from in eloquent-sluggable? At the moment even if I change "Slug" it still generates from "Title".

Appreciate any help, and thank you.